# Proof that in hyperbola sum of squares of a and b is equal to c.

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

[image]

Where c is the focus of the hyperbola.I came across this problem when I was going through the  derivation of equation of hyperbola. A substitution was made there and difference of squares of c and a were replaced by b but no proof of it was given.